# P4V - Duplicate workspace pointing to existing data

Tags: perforce, p4v

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to do the following task in p4v (I am not too familiar with P4V commands, so apologise if this is some basic command that I am missing).

Currently I have a workspace setup and data synced to my root 
e.g. C:\Data\

I access this workspace from two different windows machine. (data is on both machines at c:\Data

Now, I need to move the location of where the data is stored on ONE of the machines and not the other (Machine A : c:\Data, Machine B: D:\Data\

Is this possible to do, without having to sync all the data again from the server (there is a lot and bandwidth limitations).

My initial thoughts were to create another workspace pointing to another root, but I do not know how to get this new workspace pick up the data files at this location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do this through P4V, but it can be done with the command line client.  Here's the procedure.

After you have moved your files on machine B, and created a new workspace (without performing an "update all"), you can [pass the -k switch to the sync command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html) to let the server know what files you have.

From the web page to which I linked:

> Keep existing workspace files; update the have list without updating
>   the client workspace. Use p4 sync -k only when you need to update the
>   have list to match the actual state of the client workspace.

And the command line help has this to say:

> The -k flag updates server metadata without syncing files. It is
>   intended to enable you to ensure that the server correctly reflects
>   the state of files in the workspace while avoiding a large data
>   transfer. Caution: an erroneous update can cause the server to
>   incorrectly reflect the state of the workspace.

FYI: `p4 flush` is an alias for `p4 sync -k`

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the `AltRoots` field in the workspace.  You could have one root at `c:\data` and the other at `d:\data`.  As raven mentioned since the data is living on two separate disks you'll need to make sure that the data is kept in sync on both machines, although I assume you've already figured this part out since you've been running on two machines.

Any reason you can't just have one workspace per machine?

Comment: Thanks p4-randall
Having two workspaces (one on each machine) would be fine, I just want my new workspace to pick up the files I already have, without having to sync from the server again